# data sampling and algorithm pipeline python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

How can I link together a data sampling and classifier pipelines?

I want to perform all of the sampling techniques on all of the classifiers and select the best performer. I am performing Randomized Grid Search to select the best hyperparameters.

Is it reasonable to only perform the 6 sampling techniques on each untuned classifier (Logistic Regression l1, Logistic Regression l2, random forest), and then proceed with only tuning the one classifier that performed the best with each sampling technique?

In my previous implementation I found adasyn performed best with logistic regression, and so this is my current winner. I have implemented random forest with each of the sampling techniques and scored them, but I want to figure out how to package this nicely and streamline it.

I am mostly using imblearn and sklearn.

My question is: How can I construct a pipeline for hyperparameters, classification, and sampling?

ATTEMPT 1

```
oss= OneSidedSelection(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
enn= SMOTEENN(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
smtk= SMOTETomek(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
ada= ADASYN(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
ros= RandomOverSampler(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
smote= SMOTE(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

l1= make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    LogisticRegression(random_state=RANDOM_STATE,penalty='l1'))
l2= make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    LogisticRegression(random_state=RANDOM_STATE, penalty='l2'))
rf= make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE))

l1_pipeline = make_pipeline(oss, enn, smtk, ada, ros, smote, l1)
l2_pipeline = make_pipeline(oss, enn, smtk, ada, ros, smote, l2)
rf_pipeline = make_pipeline(oss, enn, smtk, ada, ros, smote, rf)

l1_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = l1_pipeline.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report_imbalanced(y_test, y_hat))
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
fitted_models = {}
fitted_methods = {}
for name, classification_algorithms in classification_algorithms.items():

oss= OneSidedSelection(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
enn= SMOTEENN(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
smtk= SMOTETomek(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
ada= ADASYN(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
ros= RandomOverSampler(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
smote= SMOTE(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

X_oss, y_oss= oss.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
X_enn, y_enn= enn.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
X_smtk, y_smtk= smtk.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
X_ada, y_ada= ada.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
X_ros, y_ros= ros.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
X_smote, y_smote= smote.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)

print('named X, y')


model = RandomizedSearchCV(classification_algorithms, 
hyperparameters[name], \
                           cv=10, n_jobs=-1)

model_oss = model.fit(X_oss, y_oss)
print('One Sided Selection has been fitted.')
model_enn = model.fit(X_enn, y_enn)
print('SMOTE ENN has been fitted.')
model_smtk = model.fit(X_smtk, y_smtk)
print('SMOTE Tomek has been fitted.')
model_ada = model.fit(X_ada, y_ada)
print('ADASYN has been fitted.')
model_ros = model.fit(X_ros, y_ros)
print('Random Over Sampling has been fitted.')
model_smote = model.fit(X_smote, y_smote)
print('SMOTE has been fitted.')

fitted_models[name + model_oss] = model_oss
fitted_models[name + model_enn] = model_enn
fitted_models[name + model_smtk] = model_smtk
fitted_models[name + model_ada] = model_ada
fitted_models[name + model_ros] = model_ros
fitted_models[name + model_smote] = model_smote


print(name, 'has been fitted.')
```

HYPERPARAMETERS AND CLASSIFICATION PIPELINE

```
l1_hyperparameters = {
'logisticregression__C' : np.linspace(1e-3, 1e3, 10),
}

l2_hyperparameters = {
'logisticregression__C' : np.linspace(1e-3, 1e3, 10),
}
rf_hyperparameters = {
'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [100, 200],
'randomforestclassifier__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 0.33]
}
hyperparameters = {
'l1' : l1_hyperparameters,
'l2' : l2_hyperparameters,
'rf' : rf_hyperparameters
}

classification_algorithms = {
'l1': make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    LogisticRegression(random_state=RANDOM_STATE, 
penalty='l1')),
'l2': make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    LogisticRegression(random_state=RANDOM_STATE, 
penalty='l2')),
'rf': make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE))
}
```

TRAIN AND TEST SETS

```
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
y = df.Class
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
random_state=99)
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally I wouldn't try to put the sampling technique into the pipeline, a pipeline object is intended as a robust, end-to-end method for shoving features in one end and getting predictions out the other, primarily for *generalizing your model to new data*.

Since you aren't going to be over- or under-sampling or crossvalidating your new unseen data points, over/undersampling, cross-validation, etc should be done *prior*, in order to decide what you want your pipeline to look like.

In your case, it seems like you've done good legwork up front, you said you figured out that ADASYN and LogistRegression gave you the best results, so your (pseudo)pipeline would then be

```
Out-of-pipe:
oversampled_X,y = Adasyn(X, y)

Pipeline:
{scaling/normalization if necessary,
 logisticregression with selected hyperparams}

pipeline.fit(oversampled_X,y) (or fit_transform(oversampled_X,y))

pipeline.predict(new_X)
```